# Is it possible to use data outside of GUI?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I want to use GUI to input something (anything like numbers or words), then I want to analyze what I have inputted. But it seems that I cannot do it unless I quit this GUI.

```
def Ok():
    global str_
    str_=sth.get()
    print str_

def input_():
    App=tk.Tk()
    global sth
    sth=tk.Entry(App, width=10)
    sth.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    btn=tk.Button(App,text="OK", width=10, command=Ok)
    btn.pack(side=tk.TOP)
    App.mainloop()

def test():
    input_()

print 'You input %d words'%len(str_)

if __name__=='__main__':
    from tkinter import *
    import tkinter as tk
    test()
```

In this example, I hope I can get the length of the string. I tried and I can indeed get it if I close GUI first. Is it possible to get it without closing GUI?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean, exactly, `Is it possible to use data outside of GUI?`
? Your global variable `str_` can be accessed inside of all the functions in your app, as you have written it. The print statement you have won't be triggered right now until the tkinter `mainloop()` is closed. If you create an event to trigger that print it will work. You could bind it to a button, or bind it to the user pressing enter. Right now your script simply isn't getting to that line until after `mainoop()` is quit.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I mean. I tried and it works! Thank you!

Comment: Cool! I see you are new. Welcome to SO. Consider marking this question as answered if the problem is solved. You can see this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)